# Remove from one list impact it's copy [python 2.7]

Tags: python-2.7, list, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I created a copy of a list.
When an item was removed from one copy - it was removed from the original as well.

```
a = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta']
b = a

b.remove('alpha')

print 'A list is', a
print 'B list is', b
```

How should I create an independent copy of the list, that will not impact the original?

### Late addition

To understand the reason for this mistake - one should refer to the difference between Shallow Copy and Deep Copy [Python documentation - 8.17. copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):
>
> - A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
> - A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

Comment: I just got a -1 w/o any comment - That's not helpful. If you think that question is irrelevant, wrong or useless - please explain (or tag accordingly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in-built **copy** module.

```
import copy
a = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta']
# it will perform the shallow copy
b = copy.copy(a)

b.remove('alpha')

print 'A list is', a
print 'B list is', b
```

For Python3.x. Though, **copy** module is available in Python3.x

```
a = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta']
b = a.copy()

b.remove('alpha')

print('A list is', a)
print('B list is', b)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, while I still don't understand why this is the expected behavior - it gives me a solution.